# Is there a way to use pure Javascript inside of Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have some code written in javascript that I want to execute within my program that is written in Coffeescript. Is there a way I can use the Javascript as-is inside my coffeescript file or do I need to re-write the function so it works in Coffesscript?

Comment: https://coffeescript-cookbook.github.io/chapters/syntax/embedding_javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute your code directly within a compiled CoffeeScript file you'll almost certainly need to rewrite your Javascript as (aside from arrays) the syntax in CoffeeScript is completely different: Primitives, objects, logical operators and so on.

You can however import external Javascript files using `require` and run functions, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264752/calling-javascript-function-from-coffeescript-file/17264779). Here's quick example with the linked answer as reference:

Your CoffeeScript file:

```
myExternalJs = require('myExternalJs')

    class Example

      create: -> 
        myExternalJs.myExternalFunction()
        super

    module.exports = Example
```

And then your Javascript file named `myExternalJs.js`:

```
function myExternalFunction () {
    console.log('hello from a normal javascript function!')
};

exports.myExternalFunction = myExternalFunction;
```